# How do you launch an executable with a GUI from within an already running GUI app

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have an app running in OS X that needs to launch another executable with a GUI and then close itself leaving this other GUI intact.

Right now I'm launching the other executable with **fork** then **execve** and closing the app that launched it but the new executable keeps the menu bar from the app that just closed. This stops me from running the original app until I close the window for the executable.

The only thing I've found is people saying to use **nohup** but from what I understand that just stops the program from closing when the parent closes?

**EDIT**: After looking into the functions in the first answer, I realized I should have included some more details. I am using OS X 10.8 which seems to have deprecated a lot of the File Manager API. Another important detail is that I need to pass command line arguments to the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my executable I was trying to launch, which was originally in another app package, was using the **plist** file for the application that was launching the executable. I had the executable in the Contents/MacOS folder where the executable for the original application resided. After putting the other executable in its own app package, I was able to use **fork** and **execve** on the executable within its own package to launch it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The Cocoa way would be `-[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]`.  At a slightly lower level, but still way above BSD, there's `LSOpenApplication`.